# Get text from dynamically created WinForms textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm making a windowsform with dynamically created textboxes as u see in the method.

```
    public void createPassengerBoxes(int numPassenger)
    {
        TextBox[] passengerBoxes = new TextBox[numPassenger];

        for (int u = 0; u < passengerBoxes.Count(); u++)
        {
            passengerBoxes[u] = new TextBox();
        }
        int i = 0;
        foreach (TextBox txt in passengerBoxes)
        {
            string name = "passenger" + i.ToString();

            txt.Name = name;
            txt.Text = name;
            txt.Location = new Point(244, 32 + (i * 28));
            txt.Visible = true;
            this.Controls.Add(txt);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I access the text from the boxes?

Comment: In what capacity?  I mean, just randomly accessing the control's text, or do you mean reacting to TextChanged or some other user event?

Comment: i want to make a new method which can get the text the user puts in the textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure at what point, or based on what action, you'd like to fetch the data, here's very generic method:

```
private String[] GetTextBoxStrings()
{
    List<String> list = new List<String>();
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
            list.Add(((TextBox)c).Text);
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your textbox declaration outside of the function. This makes it accessible from other functions within the class:

```
class MyFormsClass
{
    // declare textboxes at class level
    TextBox[] passengerBoxes;

    public void createPassengerBoxes(int numPassenger)
    {
       passengerBoxes = new TextBox[numPassenger];
       ...
    }

    public void OnButtonClick(...)
    {
        if (passengernBoxes != null)
        {
             foreach (TextBox txt in passengerBoxes)
             {
                 // do something with textboxes
             }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Lambda:

```
var strings = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                      .Select(c => c.Text)
                      .ToList();
```

this only work if ou have no nested controls - e.g. a pannel or a group that holds some textBoxes