# Accessing dynamically created textboxes text

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, code-behind, mailto

I have stumbled across a problem with my asp.net form.

*Within my form the end user chooses a number of textboxes to be dynamically created*, this all works fine with the following code:

```
protected void txtAmountSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int amountOfTasks;
        int.TryParse(txtAmountOfTasks.Text, out amountOfTasks);
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfTasks; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtAddItem = new TextBox();
            txtAddItem.ID = "txtAddItem" + i;
            txtAddItem.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            questionNine.Controls.Add(txtAddItem);
            txtList.Add(txtAddItem.ID);
        }
    }
```

However this has also caused a small problem for me, later on in my form on the submit button click, I send the results to the specified person it needs to go to (using smtp email). Again this part is fine, **until I am trying to retrieve the text from these dynamically created textboxes**.

**What I have tried**

1. I have tried using [this msdn access server controls ID method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) however this was not working.
2. I tried to add these new textboxes to a list, however I was unsure on how to update these textboxes when they have text in them. Therefore my results were returning null because of this.
3. I have also looked at other questions on SO such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836457/c-sharp-get-text-from-dynamically-created-textbox) however they are usually for WPF or winforms, rather than my problem with asp.net (this usually isn't an issue, but I don't need to get the text from every textbox control in my page, just the ones that were dynamically created).

I have also tried changing how I call the code that I hoped would have worked:

```
string textboxesText = string.Join("\n", txtList.Select(x => x).ToArray());
```

and then in my concatenated string (email body) I would call:

```
textboxesText
```

**The problem**

As they are dynamically created I am finding it difficult to call them by their id for example: txtExampleID.Text, also as I have to increment the ID's by one each time (so they don't override each other) it has made things a little bit more difficult for me.

I am not asking for a code solution, I would prefer pointers in the right direction as I am still learning.

*So to sum it all up:* I need to get the text from my dynamically created textboxes to add it to my email body.

Comment: You need to look into ASP .NET page life-cycle. You need to be creating your dynamic controls in `Page_Init` otherwise they won't exist later on (as you are finding).

Comment: Have you tried using a repeater to generate the textboxes?

Comment: You  have to recreate dynamically created controls with the same ID as before on each and every postback in `page_load` at the latest. You _can_ create them later the first time, though. So just persist(e.g. in `ViewState` or in a hiddenfield) a counter of already created controls that you use to recreate them in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`(if you use `ViewState`). Then you can add the new `TextBoxes` in `txtAmountSubmit_Click` and increase the counter accordingly.

Comment: @Belogix, thanks this looks like a good read, will look into this more now. I must say it looks promising, never heard of it before to be honest :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter my form only uses a postback for the submit button, and when the textboxes are created, the email should be sent before the submit postback. Does that still apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is these text boxes need **recreated** in the `Load` event of the page, every single time, so that both events and values can be hooked back up and retrieved.

I think the most straight forward approach, in your case, would be to extend idea #1 that you had already tried. Build a `List` of these controls with enough information to **recreate them** in `Load`, but you need to store that `List` in either `ViewState` or `Session`.

```
ViewState["DynamicControls"] = list;
```

or

```
Session["DynamicControls"] = list;
```

I would use `ViewState` if you can because it gets destroyed when the user leaves the page.

Comment: Good answer but don't you mean `Init` rather than `Load`? I know you can create in `Load` but always thought `Init` was the "Officially suggested" place. I could WELL be wrong!

Comment: @Belogix, you can leverage `Init` as well. It actually works in both places. I, at times, do have to leverage `Init` because I need to set some things up before the page event model gets started. Good addition!

Comment: Thanks Michael, this helped put it into context, I will try to research this more and then implement this +1, will answer this in 5mins when I can :)

Comment: @beologix: You have to use `Page_Load` if you want to evaluate the `ViewState` as suggested in his answer. And it works under certain circumstances.  "When you create dynamic controls on a Web Form, you must create the controls and add them to the controls collection in either the `Page_Init` event handler **or the `Page_Load` event handler**. Otherwise, the controls may not behave as expected." http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317515/EN-US

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, your comments and this answer has helped put this into context.